# problem with aligning text and image, react js material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm making portfolio web page using **reactJs and material-ui**, and have problem with **aligning image with text**, also there is problem with non-responsive text, basically I'm trying to make **text on left side and image on right**** something like this

[image: Text],

also with large image there is problem with non-responsive text
[image]

I would appreciate any help, here is code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Typed from "react-typed"
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import{
    Typography,
    Avatar,
    Grid, 
    Box,
    Card,
    CardMedia,
    Container
} from "@material-ui/core"
import image from "../my-picture.png";
import avatar from "../my-picture.png"
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

//CSS Styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    title: {
        color:"tomato",
        marginLeft: "2rem",
        marginTop: "15rem"
    },

    subtitle: {
        color: "tan",
        marginBottom:"1rem",    
        marginLeft: "2rem"
    },
    
    typedContainer: {
        position:"absolute",
        top:"50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        width:"100vw",
        textAlign:"left",
        zIndex: 1,
        backgorund: "#233",

    },
    cardContainer:{
        maxWidth: 590,
        marginBotoom: "5rem auto",
        marginLeft: "65rem auto",
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }

}));

  const Resume = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <>
        <Navbar />
        <Box className={classes.typedContainer}>

       
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h4">
            <Typed strings={["About"]} typeSpeed={40}/>
           </Typography>
           <br/>
            <Typography className={classes.subtitle} variant="h5">
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            </Typography>
           

           <Grid container justify="center">
             <Card className={classes.cardContainer}>
              <CardMedia 
                       component="img" 
                       alt="Project img"
                       height="400"
                       image={image} />
             </Card>
          </Grid>
           
        </Box>
        </>
    );
};

export default Resume;
```

Comment: You can use float : left css on the image to achieve the effect. Is the image is the one that is shown in the background

Comment: I tried with float ,but its not working ,image shown here is background image with non responsive text, maybe somebody who had worked with material-ui can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should make Grid container a parent for both typography and image, then use grid items inside to individually assign typography to one item and image to another.
This might help you get what you wants.